# Android: Navigate from 2 to 3 page

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

Is it possibile to navigate from main page to second page and then directly to page 3?
I try this:
Page 1:

```
    public void try_it_Click(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, wybor_roweru.class);
    StartActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Page2:

```
        public void rower_Click(View view){
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(wybor_roweru.this, MainActivity.class);
    wybor_roweru.this.startActivity(intent2);
}
```

But when I click "rower_Click" it opens my first page again...
Whats wrong?

Comment: By saying _page_ you mean _Activity_. Yes it is possible although I don't understand the purpose of the 2nd redirect

Comment: Yeah I mean activity. First activity is something like "Welcome" etc. In second activity you should choose between two options and then go to activity 3 where u get something data